# How to open .hprof with Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, profiling

I can save the memory profiling as a `hprof` by pressing this little green button. But I don't know how to open the file I created.

This instruction from the [website](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) is not clear for me:
`"You can then reopen the file in Android Studio by dragging the file into an empty editor window (or drop it in the file tab bar).`"

Where do I drop it ?What window?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out below screenshot of Android studio:

[image]

**Note**: You get this empty window in Android Studio Editor when you close all the open files.

Comment: @miracle-doh yes that will also work but i thought to give you more clear information.